# Why might I be getting "mysqli_stat() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli" error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm self teaching and am trying to make a tool to let me input mysqli functions to execute in real time to help me better understand what they do.

This is the html file I start on.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="username">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="userpassword">
<input type="submit" value="Connect">
</form>
```

This is the php file that connects, then asks for the initial function.

```
<?php
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$userpassword = trim($_POST['userpassword']);
echo $username;
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $userpassword);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo " connected successfully.<br />";
?>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value=$conn name="conn">
<input type="text" placeholder="MySQLi Operation" name="operation">
<input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

And finally the php file that is supposed to execute the function, but gives me an error. The function I'm inputting is 'mysqli_stat($conn);'. No other functions seem to work either.

```
<?php
$operation = trim($_POST['operation']);
$conn = trim($_POST['conn']);
eval($operation);
?>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="MySQLi Operation" name="operation">
<input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the runtime value of `$conn` when you execute this code?  What string are you sending from the form?  The error (if you read the whole message) seems to be telling you that you need a resource object not just a string.

Comment: I don't know what are you doing but you are doing something appallingly scaring.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass [resource](http://php.net/resource) handles through form requests. Only literals (strings, integers) can be sent as [`$_POST`](http://php.net/_POST) or [`$_GET`](http://php.net/_GET) variables. Objects and resources (database, file I/O handles) won't.

If you were to look at the resulting HTML from your second excerpt you'd see:

```
  <input type="hidden" value=resource id #2 name="conn">
                               ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

You have to set up the mysqli `$conn` in your test script anew. (Also, fine for testing, but don't use such constructs in production code.)

Comment: So I'm understanding that '$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", $username, $userpassword);' creates an object. NOT a variable with a string value? And that object is not getting passed, but instead is trying to pass a string?

Comment: Yes. `echo $conn` will turn the resource/handle into a useless string. Oh, I just noticed: you've also sent a literal `'$conn'` string even. -- For mysqli you probably would have gotten an object even, which would result in an error message when trying to print it out / cast it to a string.

Comment: Would apc_store and apc_fetch be the correct way, or at least a valid way to pass the object?

Comment: Don't make up long-winded workarounds. New mysqli object. In your test script.